# Ordering positive definite matrices with diagonal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, order-theory, symmetric-matrices, positive-definite

Let $A \succ 0$ be a Hermitian positive definite matrix. I'm trying to understand the claim that there exists a (diagonal) positive definite matrix $B \succ 0$ such that $A \prec B$, that is, $B-A$ is positive definite.

Seems elementary, but I can't seem to find a formal proof of this anywhere. Thank you!

Comment: **Hint:** Take $B$ to be a multiple of the identity matrix. It's easy to find the eigenvalues of $B - A$ in terms of the eigenvalues of $A$ for this choice.